# Issue retrieving data from SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am developing a billing related APP in Android. I have a database in which there are 4 columns:

- `ITEMNAME`
- `PRICE`
- `STOCK`
- `ID`

The `ID` column is on auto increment

In my main activity I am using a table layout with 5 columns, out of which i have problem with 2. The second column is `ITEMNAME` and third one is `PRICE`.

On the `ITEMNAME` column I am using an autocomplete `TextView` which is linked with the database. Whenever I enter the item name in the autocomplete `TextView` I want to get the price in the "price column" automatically

This is my method of adding data to the autocomplete `TextView`:

```
 public void preparedata2() {

        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor res1 = mydb.getAllData1();
        if (res1.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data in the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            while (res1.moveToNext()) {
                list.add(res1.getString(1));

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);


            }
```

This is my dynamic layout code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    tr1 = new TableRow(this);


    et6 = new EditText(this);
    et6.setText("");
    et7 = new AutoCompleteTextView(this);
    et7.setAdapter(adapter);
    et7.setThreshold(1);
    et7.setText("");
    et7.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            try {
                {
                   """" HERE I WANT HELP""""



                }



            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(shopp.this, "Something went wrong 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            ;
        }
                               });
    et8 = new EditText(this);
    et9 = new EditText(this);
    et10 = new EditText(this);
    et8.setText("");
    et9.setText("");
    et10.setText("");
    et6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext3);
    et6.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    et6.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    et7.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext3);
    et7.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    et7.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    et8.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext3);
    et8.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    et8.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    et9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext3);
    et9.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    et9.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    et10.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext3);
    et10.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    et10.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    tr1.addView(et6);
    tr1.addView(et7);
    tr1.addView(et8);
    tr1.addView(et9);
    tr1.addView(et10);
    t1.addView(tr1);
```

This is my SQLite data retrieval method:

```
public Cursor getAllData1() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res1 = db.rawQuery("select * from " + Tname, null);
    return res1;
}
```

Comment: you need to set layout params to views that you are adding dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

```
Use This Code

public ArrayList<GIF> getGIFName() {
        dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ArrayList<GIF> gifList = new ArrayList();
        String selectQuery = " SELECT * FROM gif_detail ";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
                gifList.add(new GIF(cursor.getString(1), false));
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        Log.d("TotalGIF File =", gifList.size() + "");
        return gifList;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate on your code with an explanation as to how it answers OP's question? Your code seems to relate to the retrieval of a list of GIF images from a database, which has little to no relation to what OP is asking.